# Display the same table twice, side by side, but with different filters

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have one table that I would like to display twice, side by side, where the table is filtered on either side by different criteria. So here is roughly 
(this is not the real data) how the table looks now.

```
Name |1st|2nd|3rd 
-------------------
Mark |1  | 2 | 3
Mark |2  | 4 | 6
Mark |3  | 6 | 8
Tim  |6  | 2 | 4
Tim  |10 | 11| 1
```

I'd like the results to look like this:

```
Name1|1st|2nd|3rd  Name2|1st|2nd|3rd
-------------------------------------
Mark | 1 | 2 | 3  | Tim | 6 | 2 | 4
Mark | 2 | 4 | 6  | Tim | 10| 11| 1
Mark | 3 | 6 | 8  |
```

So I can see Mark and Tim's results side by side.

When I do a full outer join I get it so that I see all the results from the first version of the table, with null from the second, and the reverse lower on the results table. This is expected, but I wanted to know how to display it how I wanted if possible. Using t-sql.

Comment: "and the reverse lower on the results table": Use something like `where p1.PersonId < p2.PersonId` so you only get one of the combos of the outer join.

Comment: SQL Server isn't a display/presentation tool.  This is quite easy to do in something like Excel.

Comment: You should be using client side software for something like that

Comment: Yet it was possible :) See below. I queried the same table twice and inserted into two new tables, then joined them by the Row_Number with full outer join so it showed them the way I wanted them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--creating table
with myTable as (
select 'mark' as Name , 1 as [1st] , 2 as [2nd] , 3 as [3rd]
union 
select 'mark' as Name , 2 as [1st] , 4 as [2nd] , 6 as [3rd]
union 
select 'mark' as Name , 3 as [1st] , 6 as [2nd] , 8 as [3rd]
union 
select 'Tim' as Name , 6 as [1st] , 2 as [2nd] , 4 as [3rd]
union 
select 'Tim' as Name , 10 as [1st] , 11 as [2nd] , 1 as [3rd]
)

--query
select * from (
select ROW_NUMBER()over (order by a.name) as Row , * from myTable as a
where Name= 'Mark' )x
left join  (
select ROW_NUMBER()over (order by a.name) as Row , * from myTable as a 
where Name= 'Tim' )y
on x.Row = y.Row
```

and here is the result :

```
Row                  Name 1st         2nd         3rd         Row                  Name 1st         2nd         3rd
-------------------- ---- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------------------- ---- ----------- ----------- -----------
1                    mark 1           2           3           1                    Tim  6           2           4
2                    mark 2           4           6           2                    Tim  10          11          1
3                    mark 3           6           8           NULL                 NULL NULL        NULL        NULL
```

Comment: This works nicely as long as the _left_ results are at least as numerous as the _right_ results. Swap `'Mark'` and `'Tim'` in the `where` clauses and the results only include two rows. A `full outer join` would address the issue.

Comment: Thank you! This wasn't exactly what I needed, but using the ROW_NUMBER() function (something I was unfamiliar with) let me full join the tables by the row number, so in the end this response helped me get where I needed to go. I marked it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using union.

Union avoids displaying duplicate data but can move it to columns like it appears you're asking.

If you can post the full query, I can demonstrate more accurately.